# Match character if present, otherwise proceed

Tags: regex, dart

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5EVbAJ/1

I have this regexp:

```
a.+?(W)?.*?(\d)
```

My intention: get the character W as group, if the character exists in the string. Otherwise return empty group. Second group is an existing number which needs to be matched, as well.

My test data:

```
1. a,W1
2. a W1
3. a,W 1
4. a, V1

5. a, W1 //fail
```

1-3 work because there is only one character between the `a` and the `W` (I believe that's because of the lazy `+?` operator). 4 works because no `W` needs to be matched.

But 5 is not working: The number group is matched correctly, but the `W` group is empty, although a `W` occurs with 2 characters between `a` and `W`.

How can I get it fixed?

Comment: `a(?:.+?(W))?.*?(\d)`? What is the language? PHP?

Comment: That seems to work. Can you explain this, please. In the end it should work with Dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
a(?:.+?(W))?.*?(\d)
```

Here, the trick is to use a non-capturing group around `.+(W)` pattern part to make the regex engine match this pattern at least once. This means the `(W)` is made an obligatory pattern, and thus Group 1 will get populated if it `W` is present after any 1 or more  characters other than line break chars after `a`.

Dart test:

```
final regex = RegExp(r'a(?:.+?(W))?.*?(\d)');
Iterable<Match> matches = regex.allMatches("5. a, W1");
for (Match match in matches) {
    print(match.group(1)); // => W
    print(match.group(2)); // => 1
}
```

Comment: What does `?:` do? In my tests it seems to be not neccessary.

Comment: @S-Man It is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions), if you use a capturing one, you will end up with a redundant `.group()` in the match result.

Comment: Ok, yes, that works also for my much bigger regexp. But I have to think about it :D, thanks!

Comment: @S-Man Please consider always posting the real patterns you are using. However, in this case, the solution is scalable enough for any pattern.